# добавить переменные в файл ansible

Tags: ansible

как в ansible, добавить переменные в файл в таком виде:

> var:
>
> > var1:
> >
> > > - динамическая переменная 1
> > > - динамическая переменная 2

пробовал blockinfile и linefile, но таку структуру сделать никак не выходит,есть ли примеры как сделать так как выше.? зарание спасибо!

Таки добился, сделал все же через block in file, но только вот проблема, ели я хочу добавить var2 и т д, то var2 со своими значениями перезаписывает var1, как это исправить?

Comment: Подробней можно? Имеется ввиду, что есть несколько переменных и нужно записать во вложенном виде?